# What gives a particle its identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, standard-model, information

A lot of very smart people have stitched together the standard model, and I accept it. I don't understand it, but I assume there should be a mechanism of sorts that gives a particle some fundamental identity, for instance markers like its spin, mass and charge. The problem of mass seems to be handled quite well. What tells a particle to have a certain spin, or charge? There are obviously clever descriptions that tell us how to find out what charge or spin it is, but is there a specific process that gives a particle its fundamental identity. I want to make an analogy here. The analogy is that in Biological systems information about us is stored in our DNA, and it gives identity to a collection of our body parts and thus us. Where is the information about what an electron should be or how it should behave stored? Is there something in Field theoretic description that makes this known? This is a genuine question, and not an attempt to get into "woowooo Physics". I have a feeling that it is probably really simple, and would like to know how this is explained. By the way, I am a huge fan of the Standard model, so I know it must have this taken care of.

Comment: You talk about DNA giving us our identities, but what gives DNA its identity? The atoms arranged within it of course. But what gives atoms their identities? Either the identity matroyshka goes on forever smaller and smaller, or at some point you reach something that *is* an identity - i.e. a fundamental particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles are described by quantum fields, and the quantum field determines the mass, spin and charge. So for example all electrons (and positrons) have the same mass, spin and (magnitude of) charge because they are all excitations of the electron quantum field. Individual electrons can have different energy and momenta, but I'm guessing you wouldn't consider these quantities part of the particle identity.

The interesting question is how we decide what quantum fields are necessary and what their properties are, and this is where [local gauge symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory) comes in. For example in quantum electrodynamics we require there to be a local $U(1)$ gauge symmetry and this requires there to be both photon and electron fields - the theory cannot be written with just a photon field or just an electron field. Likewise the $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ gauge symmetries of the electroweak force and QCD dictate the quantum fields required.

The local gauge symmetries are arbitrary in the sense that a quantum field theory can be written for many different local gauge symmetries, and the correct symmetry group is selected by comparison with experiment. However once you've selected the gauge group it's remarkable how little extra information is required. Much is made of the 19 apparently random constants required as input for the Standard Model, but 11 of these are masses and related to the Higgs coupling in ways we hope to understand one day. And even 19 constants isn't that many for a theory of everything (everything currently observable that is :-).